# regex not finding http header

Tags: python, regex, http-headers

I have a ('stolen':) Python code that use regex to parse all HTTP headers.

It is like this:

```
parser = re.compile(r'\s*(?P<key>.+\S)\s*:\s+(?P<value>.+\S)\s*')
header_list = [(key, value) for key, value in parser.findall(http_headers)]
```

Normally this works great, but the following header is not found:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

I think it can have something to do with the asterisk, but I'm not sure. 
I think the regex part:

```
P<value>.+\S
```

is used to match and group . any character + one or more times followed by \S any non-whitespace. Isn't asterisk a part of that?

Any ideas?

Comment: Your regex does not work as you expect it to. Ideally, If you must use regex I would write it a different way. But you need to change the `.+` to `.*` in your second group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is actually quite simple. The final `.+` expects any character, then followed by a `\S` another single character. tl;dr: it only matches 2 or more characters after the regex.

Use a `*` to look for 0 or more characters (plus the `\S`) instead:

```
\s*(?P<key>.+\S)\s*:\s+(?P<value>.*\S)\s*
#                                 ^ * instead of +
```

Comment: Works great! This was my very first question and I'm very happy and a little surprised over the fast response I got from all who answered. Thank you so much!